# Openlayers display Points from Geodjango REST API endpoint

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, openlayers, geojson

I am trying to display points on an OSM map using Openlayers and (Geo)Django. The points should be provided by a REST API endpoint which I want to query from within the openlayers javascript.

The JS part looks like this:

```
<div id="map" class="map shadow m-auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map', 
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(), 
          url: "http://localhost:8000/api/sites"
        })
      }) , 
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([8,48]),
      zoom: 10
    })
  });
</script>
```

The API endpoint is just serializing a django queryset and therefore returns the following:

```
[
    {
        "sid":13,
        "site_name":"Burgsteig",
        "site_notes":"Reuter.2003",
        "municipality":1047,
        "geom":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
                8.779644092464917,
                48.00504767358004
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "sid":14,
        "site_name":"Brederis, \"Weitried\"",
        "site_notes":"Hagn2002",
        "municipality":16180,
        "geom":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
                9.628734475883569,
                47.2756455228491
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "sid":15,
        "site_name":"Burgweinting, \"Villa\"/\"Mühlfeld\"",
        "site_notes":"Zintl2012, Zintl2013",
        "municipality":2767,
        "geom":{
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[
                12.11373087937611,
                49.01308089544727
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

It is just a basic API endpoint by django-rest-framework and as far as i know returns a pretty standard geoJSON format dataset. However, when running this i get an **"Uncaught Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined"**. The basemap is displaying, it is just something wrong with that geojson. As far as I understand, the API is not returning GeoJSON as in ol.format.GeoJSON() but something else instead. So how do I process this thing to be displayed on my map?

Comment: You will need a custom loader to parse that structure and create OpenLayers features.  Based on this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/flight-animation.html here is code which handles your data structure https://codesandbox.io/s/flight-animation-forked-qz4uvz?file=/main.js  Here is another example of a custom loader https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wind-arrows.html

Comment: Thank you for that, I am right now trying to get it working. There seem to be some problems with import statements:

**"Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"**

so I am really looking foreward to many fun hours with this...

Comment: Your script is written for use with the ol.js build as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html  Instead of using imports e.g. for `import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';` you replace the import name `VectorSource` in the subsequent code with its path `ol.source.Vector`.

Comment: Yeah... I really appreciate your efforts but I think I will leave the mapping part out for now. Unfortunately, it's all far too incomprehensible for my abilities.